# How to visualize array of objects in Kibana?

Tags: lucene, kibana, elastic-stack, vega, vega-lite

I have a few documents of the below format.

Document1:

```
{
   "_index":    "myIndex",
    "preferenceCount": [
      {
        "name": "apple",
        "count": 1
      },
      {
        "name": "mango",
        "count": 1
      },
      {
        "name": "apple",
        "count": 1
      }
    ]
}
```

Document2:

```
{
   "_index":    "myIndex",
    "preferenceCount": [
      {
        "name": "mango",
        "count": 1
      },
      {
        "name": "mango",
        "count": 1
      },
      {
        "name": "orange",
        "count": 1
      }
    ]
}
```

I want to visualise this data aggregated in such a way that I get the below graph (sorry for not uploading picture)

```
apple:   2 (sum of count for name = apple across documents in time range)
mango:   3
orange:  1
```

I tried

```
sum(preferenceCount.count) groupBy (preferenceCount.name.keyword)
```

But that sums count across documents and displays below graph

```
apple:  3
mango:  6
orange: 3
```

Please let me know how might I achieve this.

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I don't know kibana but in Vega-Lite, you can extract data from a property:

```
{
  "data": {
    "property": "preferenceCount",
    "type": "json",
    ...
  }
}
```